# How to SSH from a Kubernetes pod into a server

Tags: linux, kubernetes, ssh

I have an apache server running on a kubernetes pod. I have a requirement where the API running  on the web-server has to SSH into a Linux server that is independent/not related to the kubernetes cluster.

Usually, if the apache server runs on a linux server, for the process to SSH into a different linux server, i use SSH keys. Put the id_rsa.pub of the linux server on which the apache web-server is running on, into the .ssh/authorized_keys of the target linux server.

How to achieve a similar result with the web-server running on a kubernetes pod?

Comment: The same way. Your question seems to be how you go about transferring the public key (stored in the Docker image?) to the remote server?

Comment: @chepner, But pods may get destroyed and re-created. So, the SSH key might change everytime? 
How to handle that?

Comment: Also, yes, how to transfer the public key to remote server? :)

Comment: @Vijay why generate the SSH key each time the pod is created?

Comment: Okay, i think i'm cloudy in understanding the concepts. 
So, pods run in container, and we transfer the keys of container which runs the pod, to remote server? If I'm understanding it correct?

Comment: Containers are created from images. If the key is stored in the image (probably not idea), then you simply need to transfer the public key *once* to the remote server, and each container can connect. If the container generates a new key on start up, then you'll need to process for grabbing the public key from the container and transferring it to the remote host.

Answer (score 0):

As `chepner` suggested you can create your image along with the ssh keys. However he has also mentioned that it is not suggested as it might result in a security incident. So, instead of directly building images along with SSH files you can pass them as kubernetes secrets. Follow this [document](https://unofficial-kubernetes.readthedocs.io/en/latest/concepts/configuration/secret/#:%7E:text=Use%20cases-,Use%2DCase%3A%20Pod%20with%20ssh%20keys,-Create%20a%20secret) for more information and you also automate the process of key-rotation using a CICD pipeline.

Comment: @vijay is your issue resolved revert back if you are still facing the issue..